# removing backgroundcolor of a view in android

Tags: android, background-color

Removing Background color in Android

I have set `backgroundColor` in code like this,

```
View.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
```

How to remove this background color on some event?

Comment: You could set it to transparent: View.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); Or android.R.color.transparent

Comment: just found out that , another way to set it to transparent would be , View.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: If you just want to use the parent's background, you can remove the entire child's background with: view.setBackgroundResource(0);

Comment: donot works for me toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); @sat 
donot works for me toolbar.setBackgroundColor(0); Also View.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); donot works for me

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You should try setting the background color to transparent:

`view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);`

Comment: Ok , I thought there will be something to remove backgroundcolor property.

Comment: Since it's an int I don't think you can sort of "null" it out, this answer should work fine with 0x00AAF890 also (or any 0x00------) since the first two 0's set the opacity to 0% which is to say there is not background color.

Answer (score 51):

You can use

`View.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

or

`View.setBackgroundColor(0);`

or even

`View.setBackground(null);`

Please remember that **almost everything visible on the screen extends View**, like a Button, TextView, ImageView, any kind of Layout, so this can be done to almost everything.

**Bonus point!**

Instead of using `View.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);` it is sooooooooo much better to create a color filter with **android.graphics.PorterDuff.MULTIPLY** option and, if needed, just clear the filter.

Using the color filter, colors look much better because it won't be that "flat" color but a nicer tone of the chosen color.

A light red background would be

`View.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x3FFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);`

To "remove" the color, just use 
`View.getBackground().clearColorFilter();`

Comment: Color.TRANSPARENT looks much cleaner than 0x0000000. You have my upvote!

Comment: Thanks @Teilmann. I also added the "Color Filter" option that, in my opinion, looks much better compared to setBackground. You should try it!

Answer (score 16):

All of the answers about setting color to transparent will work *technically*. But there are two problems with these approaches:

1. You'll end up with [overdraw](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/overdraw.html).
2. There is a better way:

If you look at how `View.setBackgroundColor(int color)` works you'll see a pretty easy solution:

```
/**
 * Sets the background color for this view.
 * @param color the color of the background
 */
@RemotableViewMethod
public void setBackgroundColor(@ColorInt int color) {
    if (mBackground instanceof ColorDrawable) {
        ((ColorDrawable) mBackground.mutate()).setColor(color);
        computeOpaqueFlags();
        mBackgroundResource = 0;
    } else {
        setBackground(new ColorDrawable(color));
    }
}
```

The color `int` is just converted to a `ColorDrawable` and then passed to `setBackground(Drawable drawable)`. So the solution to remove background color is to just null out the background with:

```
myView.setBackground(null);
```

Comment: This is the appropriate answer. Making the background transparent requires processing time, while _removing the background_ doesn't.

Comment: setBackground is from API 16, how can I do that for lower APIs?

Comment: for lower api you should use myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: this should be accepted answer, because transparent background has hidden costs

Answer (score 6):

`View.setBackgroundColor(0);` also works. It isn't necessary to put all those zeros.

Answer (score 0):

**Choose Any one**

```
View.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    or

    View.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

Comment: How does this add to the existing answers?